# Redux Toolkit: have two consecutive dispatch and the latter is dependent upon the former

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I have an action called `getRole` and an action called `getPoliciesFrom`. `getRole` returns the role and `getPoliciesFrom` returns a list of policies attached to that role. And then I need to dispatch these actions to support a feature.

I dispatch `getRole` in my `useEffect` and I use `useSelector` to get the `role` as the state

```js
const role = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.settings.role);

//...

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getRole());
}, [dispatch]);
```

now in order to get the policies, I thought of two options: either I add a conditional check to see if `role` is null, when it is not `null`, dispatch the `getPoliciesFrom` and pass in `role` as its argument. so this would look like this:

```
const role = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.settings.role);

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getRole());
  if(role) {
    dispatch(getPoliciesFrom(role));
  }
}, [dispatch]);
```

**Or** I use the promise returned by the first dispatch and attach the second dispatch in the `then` when the promise resolves. That would look something like this

```
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getRole()).then(result => dispatch(getPoliciesFrom(result))
}, [dispatch]);
```

Both seem to be working. but for the second approach my ts compiler is yelling at me for the `then` I attached to the dispatch, saying that

> Property 'then' does not exist on type 'AsyncThunkAction<{ RoleArn:
> null; } | { RoleArn: string | undefined; }, void, {}>'.

But I did return the results from `getRole`. Here is the code for it

```
export const getRole = createAsyncThunk(
  "settings/getRole",

  async () => {
    let response: GetServiceRoleForAccountResponse;

    try {
      response = await api.getServiceRoleForAccount().promise();
    } catch (error) {
      if (
        error.statusCode === notAssociatedStatusCode &&
        error.message === notAssociatedErrorMessage
      ) {
        return { role: null };
      }

      throw error;
    }

    return { role: response.role };
  }
);
```

Also I am not sure how I can properly type the `result` that gets back from the promise.

And most importantly, which approach is better here?

Comment: Make sure you return the result in getRole: `const getRole = arg => dispatch => {return async.then((role)=>{dispatch(someAction);return role;})}`

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the result in getRole, here is a working example of a thunk action returning a promise that resolves to a value:

```js
const { Provider, useDispatch, useSelector } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } = Redux;

const initialState = {
  num: 0,
};
//action types
const OK = 'OK';
//action creators
const ok = (num) => (dispatch) =>
  //returning a promise
  new Promise((resolve) =>
    setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch({
        type: OK,
        payload: num,
      });
      //resolving the promise to a value
      resolve(num);
    }, 2000)
  );

const reducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  if (type === OK) {
    return { num: payload };
  }
  return state;
};
//selectors
const selectNum = (state) => state.num;
//creating store with redux dev tools
const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(
      ({ dispatch, getState }) => (next) => (action) =>
        typeof action === 'function'
          ? action(dispatch, getState)
          : next(action)
    )
  )
);
const App = () => {
  const num = useSelector(selectNum);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(ok(88)).then((num) =>
      console.log('num here is:', num)
    );
  }, [dispatch]);
  console.log('num in render:', num);
  return String(num);
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I actually did return the result from `getRole`. I've updated my answer to add a snippet of what `getRole` looks like. Btw which approach do you think is better?